# Is is possible to run Android Service after app deinstallation?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

i want to run a script even if the Task is destroyed. That works fine but is it possible to keep this service running, after the user destroyes the app?
I read something about binding the service but this is not working for me.

Comment: obviously not, that would be a security problem. i would delete the app but it would still have parts of it running. Also please clarify whether you mean destroy or deinstall. Those are not the same

Comment: Just want some clarification, what do you mean by "destroys app"?  You mentioned deinstallation in the title but you talk about destroys app, which sounds like app has stopped running.

Comment: what do u mean by destroy app?

Comment: i mean after the app is deinstallated. when the app is destroyed, my service still runs.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the user uninstalls the app, all components are destroyed and removed from the operating system.

However, you can make a Service automatically restart after the app is killed (but not uninstalled) by starting through `context.startService(Intent)`, and returning `Service.START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```